# Order firebase object array by Timestamp after foreach loop

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework

I get data from firestore and like to order it by Server Timestamp. The problem is that I get each document separately and push it into a new array..

```
  async letzteKontakteAbrufen(userid: string): Promise<LetzteKontakte[]> {
let arrRef = [];
const docref = await getDocs(collection(this.afStore, 'Nutzer', userid, 'chats'));
docref.forEach(async (docu) => {
  const docid = docu.data().id;
  console.log('DOKUMENTID: ', docid);
  const docReff = doc(this.afStore, 'Chat', docid);
  let objref = await (await getDoc(docReff)).data();
  objref.id = docid //Eegänzt das Object um die Property "id"
  arrRef.push(objref)
});
const sortMessages = arrRef.sort((a, b) => {
  return a.time - b.time
})
return sortMessages}
```

So I can't use the "orderby" condition. After the push method I tried to order it in "sortMessages", but I don't know how to sort for Firebase Timestamp after my query.
Hope someone can help and change "sortMessages" correctly..

This is an example of my object array what have to be sorted:

```
arrRef = [{firstname: Tommy, lastname: Miller, time: "Firebase serverTimestamp"}, { ... }]
```

Comment: Could you please log a server timestamp and show what the data structure is? I hope it's not just a string with the words `"Firebase serverTimestamp"` like you've shown.

Comment: Nooo.. it's a normal timestamp from firebase like {seconds: 1655385805, nanoseconds: 243000000}. Thats why I put it in quotation marks.

Comment: So then `return a.time.seconds - b.time.seconds`

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I tried your solution, but it's not working.. Is there another way to sort a firebase timestamp inside an object array?